# How to prevent Tin ions from precipitating as Tin(II,IV) Hydroxides

Tags: acid-base, solutions, precipitation

Alright, so Tin ions in most of it's salts have the propensity to form Tin(II,IV) Hydroxides and then precipitating out of aqueous solutions. What can I throw in the solutions to prevent this? Using Tin Fluoroborate doesn't precipitate Hydroxides, but I don't have access Fluoroborates. I really don't want very acidic solutions, either, for safety purposes.

Is there any complexes out there that does the job?

Comment: A pH of about 3 or 4 should work as far as I remember from my students time. Do you consider this to be too acidic?

Comment: as long as not strongly acidic enough to readily oxidize zinc metal, but i don't know how low the pH has to be to oxidize zinc.

Comment: how about ketones and saccharides?

Comment: @Badadeeboop do you like chelants?